# Grails JSON API localised number separator

Tags: grails, number-formatting

How do you convert numbers sended (and provided) by JSON API for different countries' users?

F.e.

- in Poland we use *coma* in float numbers: 1,500 (one and half)
- in USA they use *coma* to separate thounsands and *dot* to separate float numbers: 1,500 (one thousand five hundred), 1.500 (one and half).

Do you know any efficient way to handle it? (either for request params and response).

---

I've projects using different grails versions: 2.3.7 and 2.4.5.

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/guide/i18n.html#changingLocales

Comment: I'm using this for messages, but there is nothing about localised numbers.

Comment: If as part of a request you send an `Accept-Language` header param set to say `en-US` then Grails should parse the number appropriately for you.

Comment: I'm talking about `request.JSON` and sended back `object as JSON` and I'm afraid you're talking about `request.params`.

Comment: JSON is not localized and always uses `.` for decimal characters. In Java you cannot use `1,5` too you always has to use `1.5`. It seems you are sending numbers as string instead of numbers

Comment: Please send it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not localized and always uses `.` for decimal characters.

In Javascript code you cannot use `1,5` either. You always have to use `1.5`. It seems you are sending numbers as string instead of numbers and Grails has to convert them to numbers using default localization-aware converters.